# SSD-shufflenet-V2-FPN is Slower than Mobilenet V2

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have write some custom code on [tensorflow-
models/object_detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to implement the `SSD-shufflenet-v2-FPN` (based on shufflenet v2 1.0) and SSD-mobilenet-v2-FPN (based on mobilenet v2 1.0). I trained them on my own data set.

Their precision is similar, but the performance speed varies greatly:
SSD-shufflenet-v2-fpn takes three times as long as SSD-mobilenet-v2-fpn when using the same input.(With 1080*1920 input,4 * ARM Cortex-A72 Cores and Android 8.0,SSD-shufflenet-v2-fpn cost 1200ms per image,SSD-mobilenet-v2-fpn just 400ms)

I tried to replace my code with a [third-party basic network structure](https://github.com/TropComplique/shufflenet-v2-tensorflow) - Nothing changed.

In the shufflenet v2's paper, shufflenet v2 1.0 is much faster than mobilenet v2 1.0, either on GPU or ARM.Has anyone tried these two networks?

ps: Sorry, I have no condition to test the performance and coco classification performance of the basic network on the imagenet classification. I only have one GTX1080TI that often overheats and is thus too slow to complete these.

The way to implement a modified version of SSD is very simple. After completing the code of the shufflenet v2, modify `ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_feature_extractor.py`

Answer (score 0):

In the original paper of **MobileNetV2**: (http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Sandler_MobileNetV2_Inverted_Residuals_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf), there is a comparison between the **MobileNetV2** and **ShuffleNet** architectures, in section **6.2**.

One may observe that the CPU time on ShuffleNet is not measured, because, as the authors mention that, there wasn't  an efficient implementation of group convolution and shuffling operations implemented in Tensorflow mobile framework when experiments took place. That may be the reason in your case too.